# How to specify StrictHostKeyChecking as no while using Net::SSH::Perl?

Tags: perl, ssh, perl-module

I tried using StrictHostKeyChecking for Net::SSH::Perl as below and it didn't work.

```
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new("$server", debug => 1, protocol => 2, StrictHostKeyChecking => "no") or die "Error connecting server $server";
```

Please let me know how to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*StrictHostKeyChecking* is not one of the named parameters accepted by method "new". In such cases as mentioned in the documentation of [Net::SSH::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~schwigon/Net-SSH-Perl-1.36/lib/Net/SSH/Perl.pm) you can pass value for that parameter using the *options* parameter. Say something like below would work:

```
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new("$server",
                               debug => 1, protocol => 2,
                               options=> ["StrictHostKeyChecking  no"]);
```

Comment: This works only when we use it with options "CheckHostIP no" and "UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null"

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps,

```
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($server,
  debug => 1, 
  protocol => 2,
  strict_host_key_checking => "no"
) or die "Error connecting server $server";
```